# How to trigger a function that is exported by a socket

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I'm creating an realtime chatting application with react and socket.io. I tried to trigger a function declared in socket.on function from another class, but the function wasn't triggered at all. Where do I need to fix my code?

Here is what I have tried:

**Api.js**

```
import openSocket from 'socket.io-client';
import axios from 'axios';
const socket = openSocket("http://localhost:3000/")

function connect(receiver_id) { 
    socket.on(receiver_id, (from_id, message)=> {
        console.log("SENDER: " + from_id);
        pushToArray(message);
    });
}

function pushToArray(message){

}

export { connect, socket, pushToArray };
```

**HomePage.js**

```
import { socket, pushToArray } from '../Api';

class HomePage extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.push = this.push.bind(pushToArray);
    }

    push = (message) => {
        console.log("Triggered"); 
        console.log(message); 
    }

     render(){
        return (
            <div>

            </div>
        );
    }
}


export default HomePage;
```

Comment: Please, paste your code via copy and paste into your question. See Help Center for more information how to write a good question.

Comment: Where are you calling function `connect` that subscribes to your event?